# PHP Registration Form and Database Error

Tags: database, forms, php

I've asked a few questions on here and got lots of help, so I will thank in advance for my next question. I've been trying to create Registration System for my Scout Group (Registering for Camps) and I've gotten stuck up to the point where I can't send the data from the form into the database, and then send a confirmation email using the PHP Mail function.

Bellow is my form code:

```
    <form action="include/spud/registration.php">

                          <h2>Group Information:</h2>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td>Group Name (# &amp; Name):
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="group_name" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Group Location (City it is located in: e.g. Mississauga):
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="group_location" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Number of Youth Attending:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="group_attending" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <h2>Contact Information:</h2>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="50%">First Name:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="name_first" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                              <td>Last Name:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="name_last" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Address:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="address" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                              <td>Address 2 (Optional):
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="address2" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>City:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="city" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                              <td>Province or State:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="prov_state" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td>Country:
                              <br/>
                              <div class="input-control select">
                                  <select>
                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                    <option name="country">Canada</option>
                                    <option name="country">United States</option>
                                    <option name="country">Scotland</option>
                                    <option name="country">Another Country</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>Postal Code (ZIP):
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="zip_code" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="50%">Telephone:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="telephone" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                              <td>Telephone (Residential or Business: Optional):
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="telephone2" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td>Email:
                              <br />
                              <div class="input-control text">
                                  <input type="text" name="email" />
                                  <button class="btn-clear"></button>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <div class="place-left">
                              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                              <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="place-right">
                              <a href="#info" class="button">Spud Camp Information</a>
                          </div>
                        </form>
```

Then it sends it to the database stage:

```
    <?php

require_once('../database.php');

/*
* Insert the data into the Database
*/

    $qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO 

    spudcamp(group_name,group_location,group_attending,name_first,name_last,address,address2,city,prov_state,country,zip_code,telephone,telephone2,email)

    VALUES('$_POST[group_name]','$_POST[group_location]','$_POST[group_attending]','$_POST[name_first]','$_POST[name_last]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[address2]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[prov_state]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[zip_code]','$_POST[telephone]','$_POST[telephone2]','$_POST[email]', NOW() )

    ", $con);

if(!$qry)
{
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
else
{
    header('location:../../spud-camp.php');
}

/*
* Send an Email to Administration and to the Signed up person
*/

include('receipt_email.php');

    ?>
```

then the receipt_email.php stage:

```
    <?php

    /*
    * Receipt Emailer
    */


    $message = '

    <html>
    <body style="color: #000;font-family:arial;">


    <p>Thank you&#44; <b>';

    $message .= $_POST[name_first] . ' ';
    $message .= $_POST[name_last];

    $message .= '</b>&#44; for your submission&#46;<br>';
    $message .=  'We hope that the <b>';
    $message .= $_POST[group_name];
    $message .= '</b><br>
                  <b>Please print this page for your records.</b><br><BR>
                      Your registration submitted on ';
    $message .= date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    $message .= ' is as follows&#58;<br><br>
      Registration &#35;&#58; <B>';

    $message .= '</B><br>
      Group Name&#58; <B>';
    $message .= $_POST[group_name];
    $message .= '</B><br>
      First Name&#58; <B>';
    $message .= $_POST[name_first];  
    $message .= '</B>  <br>
      Last Name&#58; <B>';
    $message .= $_POST[name_last];
    $message .= '</B><br>
     Address 1&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[address1];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Address 2&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[address2];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      City&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[city];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Prov&#47;State&#58; <B>';

    $message .=  $_POST[prov_state];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Postal Code&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[zip_code];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Country&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[country];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Telephone &#35;&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[telephone];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      Business Phone &#35;&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[telephone2];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      E&#45;mail&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[email];
    $message .=  '</B><br>
      &#35; Attending&#58; <B>';
    $message .=  $_POST[group_attending];
    $message .=  '</B></p>';

    $message .= '
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // multiple recipients
    $to  = $_POST[email] . ", "; // note the comma
    $to .= '';

    // subject
    $subject = '';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: Registrant <' . $_POST[email] . ">\n";
    $headers .= ' <>' . "\n";

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    ?>
```

I have removed some places, that way i don't have my email on the page for spammers. Anyways thanks in advance I really will appreciate it :D

Comment: What errors are you getting? what are you expecting to happen? what is happening? Whats the difference in what your getting & what your expecting?

Comment: You can't break this down into a simpler use case?

Comment: The error I am currently getting is: Query Failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 ... And I'm getting that error because i played around with it a bit. I wasn;t getting an error before, but nothing was happaning, like the mail wasn't getting received and it was going into the database as an empty row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close! with line 9:

```
$qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO...
```

theres a **NOW()** at the end:

```
...'$_POST[email]', NOW())
```

remove the NOW(), so just

```
...'$_POST[email]')
```

see how that goes :)

Comment: I'm not even sure why I put that NOW thing there in the first place lol... it removed my error, but a blank row is being put into the database....?

Comment: i also just checked again to see if that black row is still being put in... And I'm now getting this: Query Failed: Duplicate entry '0' for key 1 ... I will check to see if I have auto_increment set or not... EDIT: I fixed this problem, although non of the data is being put into the database

Comment: your fast at solving problems hah. just sounds like the form isnt being submitted properly. to see if this is the truth, try just setting all fields to strings, instead of $_POST's. eg: `'$_POST[email]'` to just `'apples'`. a row should then be inserted :)

Comment: Michael, someone just beet you to it, but i really appreciate for your effort in the problem. (for note) I fixed the insert problem with the method='post' in the <form> html code.

Comment: oh yeah, missed that haha. no worries, grats on fixing the code!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't specified POST as the form method, but are trying to acess post variables. Set the form method to post.

Comment: That seems to be working :D On somewhat of the same note, I have a combobox in there for country selection, nothing in the part was entered into the database, is there a specific reason why? And the phpmail function doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The name="country" should be on the select tag not the options.

Comment: @TehJamDude, I noticed you switched the accepted answer and was wondering if you could explain why.